# 404 when servlet is invoked but works directly when url to servlet is used from browser

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

**Problem**: When I invoke url (url-mapping) directly in the browser it works pretty well but when I use `post` method to invoke servlet from jsp file, it does not work but gives an error:

> Type Status Report
>
> Message /HelloWorld/myservlet
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

**Jsp page**:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post"  action="myservlet">
            <input type="submit" value ="send">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeehttp://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>helloworld2</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>apress.helloworld.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Servlet code:**

```
    package apress.helloworld;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


    public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        //System.out.println("Get Method Called");

          try { response.setContentType("text/html");
        `enter code here`  PrintWriter printwriter = response.getWriter(); 
          printwriter.println("<h2>");
          printwriter.println("Hello World");
          printwriter.println("</h2>"); 
          } 
          catch
          (IOException ex) 
          { ex.printStackTrace(); }


    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          try { resp.setContentType("text/html");
          PrintWriter printwriter = resp.getWriter(); 
          printwriter.println("<h2>");
          printwriter.println("Hello World");
          printwriter.println("</h2>"); 
          } 
          catch
          (IOException ex) 
          { ex.printStackTrace(); }


        }



   }
```

Comment: You need to pass  'hello' instead of 'mysevlet' because you have given  <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern> .

Comment: Which url you are passing from browser?

Comment: Sanjay, I am using http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/hello which works however when I use button on the form to invoke servelet, it navigates to http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/myservlet which does not work. The web.xml has mapping for myservlet to Servlet-class which is servlet under package 'apress.helloworld.HelloWorld' class whose doGet method gets executed because action is pointing to that servlet but it does not work.

Comment: Change your `action="myservlet"` to `action="/hello"`

Comment: In form pass action="hello" instead of action="myservlet".

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post"  action="hello">
            <input type="submit" value ="send">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**use Above code
in HTML form action="url-mapping" you have to mention url pattern of servlet not servlet name refer your web.xml**